# findCircle from SimpleCV returns NoneType

Tags: simplecv

I am doing example from the:

[COMPUTER VISION USING SIMPLECV AND THE RASPBERRY PI](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/carbajal/EmbeddedSystems/SLIDES/Computer%20Vision/Computer%20Vision%20using%20SimpleCV%20and%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi.pdf)
by Cuauhtemoc Carbajal

that is on the page 75. I have written the program, and when I start it I always get that img.findCircle(canny=200,thresh=250,distance=15) function has returned a NoneType, and it cant do nothing.

I hope that there is here somebody who can explain this to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A NoneType simply means that the search failed to find any circle above the threshold you set. Try lowering both the canny and the thresh parameter.